# Choosing the data type to post in a curl payload

Tags: php, curl

I have an application that i want to access via curl and the way i am doing that is via a curl api. I am inserting a document with the details i have. The document accepts a string, geopoint and integer32/64.

Since the server is some sort of database, is it possible to decide what data type to send as a json payload since some of the fields must be strings and others integers

```
<?php       
        
        $YOUR_API_KEY =  base64_encode("77777");

        $ch = curl_init();
        $payload = '{"property_owner_id":"'.$property_owner_id.'","property_name":"'.$property_name.'","property_country":"'.$property_country.'","property_address":"'.$property_address.'","property_city":"'.$property_city.'","property_star_rating":'$property_star_rating',"property_reviews_score":'$property_reviews_score',"property_price_per_night_usd":'$property_price_per_night_usd',"property_price_per_night_euro":'$property_price_per_night_euro',"property_price_per_night_pound":'$property_price_per_night_pound',"property_price_per_night_sfr":'$property_price_per_night_sfr',"property_price_per_night_auz":'$property_price_per_night_auz',"property_price_per_night_rem":'$property_price_per_night_rem',"property_price_per_night_yen":'$property_price_per_night_yen',"property_image":"'.$property_image.'","property_tv":"'.$property_tv.'","property_radio":"'.$property_radio.'","property_breakfast":"'.$property_breakfast.'","property_bed_type":"'.$property_bed_type.'","property_kitchennete":"'.$property_kitchennete.'","property_region":"'.$property_region.'","property_chain_name":"'.$property_chain_name.'","property_status":"'.$property_status.'","property_maximum_occupancy_capacity":'$property_maximum_occupancy_capacity',"property_remaining_occupancy_capacity":'$property_remaining_occupancy_capacity',"property_date_added":"'.$property_date_added.'","property_date_updated":"'.$property_date_updated.'","property_coordinates": ['$coordinates']}';
        $pe = json_encode($payload);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8108/collections/mh_props/documents');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pe);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $YOUR_API_KEY . ':' . '');

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close ($ch);
```

For instance

```
"property_city":"'.$property_city.'","property_star_rating":'$property_star_rating',
```

`$property_city` should be a string and `$property_star_rating` should be an integer. I have prepared some data that is stored in `$property_city` as a string and `$property_star_rating` as an integer.

This is the curl equivalent without php

```
curl "http://localhost:8108/collections/mh_props/documents" -X POST \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "X-TYPESENSE-API-KEY: " \
        -d '{"property_owner_id":"1","property_name":"Louvre Museuem","property_country":"", "property_address":"","property_city":"","property_star_rating":4,"property_reviews_score":6,"property_price_per_night_usd":100,"property_price_per_night_euro":120,"property_price_per_night_pound":130,"property_price_per_night_sfr":200,"property_price_per_night_auz":122,"property_price_per_night_rem":134,"property_price_per_night_yen":211,"property_image":"","property_tv":"","property_radio":"","property_breakfast":"","property_bed_type":"","property_kitchennete":"","property_region":"","property_chain_name":"","property_status":"","property_maximum_occupancy_capacity":23,"property_remaining_occupancy_capacity":20,"property_date_added":"","property_date_updated":"","property_coordinates": [48.86093481609114, 2.33698396872901]}'
```

Is it possible to make a data type distinction when posting the data using json?

Comment: Having a hard time understanding the actual question. In Json, a number `{ a: 1 }` vs a string `{ a: "1" }` seems enough?

Comment: I know , for instance `"property_star_rating":"'.$property_star_rating.'",`  is an integer, how would i pass it since when we encode everything, everything is stringfied

Comment: Still not sure what the question is. Guess @Jim is pointing in the right direction, you shouldn't make JSON strings by contacting strings, use the build-in php functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build up some array first containing your data.

For example

```
$a = ["key1" => 3, "key2" => "344"];
```

and do some `json_encode($a)` which will automatically do the number/string conversion part for you

Result will be

```
{"key1":3,"key2":"344"}
```

This will guarantee to have always a proper json string without fiddling around with string concats

PS: JSON does not care about complex types like geopoints etc. Therefore you might always want to convert to simple types like numbers and/or strings